# Read a path from variable

Tags: python, blender

I have a fairly simple problem. I have an entry field where the user should paste a path.

Then I have a variable that gets what's inside the entry field. All of this happens inside of Blender, so it looks like this:

```
path_store = bpy.context.scene.PathProp.path_p
```

Then later I need to call this path inside of a Function that accepts a path:

```
Function(filepath="C:\\Path")
```

so usually a path works perfectly this way:

```
Function(filepath = r"C:\path")
```

But when I store the path into a variable:

```
path = "C:\path"
```

I have no idea how to write it. I tried this:

```
Function(filepath = r(path))
```

but it gives an error "r" is not defined..

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you use input(), it reads correcty paths as in your example

Comment: Whats wrong with using a raw string like your first snippet?

Comment: if you have, instead, a string with single escapes, you can use path.encode('unicode_escape')

Comment: try without 'r', like filepath = path, or directly use path

Comment: @Sayse The problem with the wrong string is that I don't want to hard-code it. I'm using an entry field, then accessing it to get what's written in there, store it in a variable and use it for a path to export something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `input()` your example works.
If you have a string variable like your example and you want to "turn it" to a raw string-like string (double escapes, in your case), you can use `str.encode()`

```
path.encode('unicode_escape')
```

converts `"C:\path"` to `"C:\\path"`

Comment: Thank you! This is needed for a Blender script. It turned out that using blenders input fields automatically converts it